# Scheduler service in Wildfly 9

Tags: java, jboss, scheduled-tasks, wildfly, scheduler

My application is running on JBoss 4.2.3 in a clustered environment. There is a scheduler service which pulls data from the database in every 10 sec. We achieved this by placing **-service.xml in deployments folder and by implementing "org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean" interface in JBoss 4.2.3.

Now, i am upgrading jboss to Wildfly 9. As we cannot achieve scheduler service in wildfly with the existing mechanism(wildfly doesn't support org.jboss.varia.scheduler.SingleScheduleProvider), i am looking at alternatives EJB TimerService & ManagedScheduledExecutorService. Our requirement is to run the scheduled service only in one node of the cluster which we achieved in jboss 4 using HASingletonDeployer.

My qns:

1. Which is better - EJB TimerService or
   ManagedScheduledExecutorService? My Scheduler task should invoke
   only if the previous task is finished i.e. i don't need concurrent
   tasks.
2. How can we achieve that the scheduled task/method run only on one
       node in a cluster?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ManagedScheduledExecutorService has scheduleWithFixedDelay which is perfect for first question. It spawns same thread specified time after completition of task

Comment: take a look in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers